# Setting up a dualboot by installing cloned partitions using clonezilla

Tags: windows-7, linux, partitioning, grub

I'm trying to setup a dual boot system where I have Windows 7 and Linux Mint. Here's the kicker both are partitions I've saved using Clonzezilla from different places and to make matters worse Linux Mint is formated as a LVM. I need both of these images specifically as windows is a corporate image that I must use and the other is a development image that took me a week to setup.

I've gotten it almost all working but my issue is that I can't get clonezilla to not mess up the partition table of Windows when installing Mint or vise-vera. I can use the (-k1 option) which doens't copy the partition table but then I have a unusable partition when it clones and I'm not sure how to fix the partition table. Here's what I'm doing:

- Using Gparted to make partitions sda1 40GB ntfs (windows), sda2
  extended 70GB, sda5 lvm2 pv 69.99 GB (Linux), sda3 500MB (GRUB)
- Clonezilla windows image into sda1 partition (keeping partition
  table)
- Clonezilla linux image into sda5 partition (not recreating partition
  table)

After all that I can boot into windows using the default MBR. I can use boot-repair cd to reinstall GRUB which will see Windows 7 but I can't get it to see the Linux OS. I'm thinking its because of the sda5 partition but I'm not sure any ideas on what I could do to get this working or where I might be going wrong. If there is any additional detail you need please let me know and I'll edit as this is a lot.

Answer (score 1):

After setting up your new disk, you should try using BootRepair: download a Ubuntu live image, put it onto a USB stick, boot from it, choose *Try Ubuntu without installing it*, open a terminal, and follow the instructions contained [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). It is not perfect, but gets its job done a fair fraction of the time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I've tried that approach. I don't think boot repair fixes the partitions of LVMs or at least it hasn't for me.